# How to use inheritance with higher-kinded types?

Tags: scala, inheritance, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to use inheritance for classes that contains type parameters but scala compiler could not inherit types properly.

```
trait Printer[X] {
  def pretty(src : X) : String
}

final case class Higher[P[_] <: Printer[_], X](printer : P[X]) {
  def pass(arg : X) : String = {
    val pr : Printer[X] = printer
    pr.pretty(arg)
  }
}
```

compiler output:

```
InheritanceFailed.scala:23: error: type mismatch;
 found   : P[X]
 required: test.failedinheritance.Inner.Printer[X]

      val pr : Printer[X] = printer
                            ^
one error found
```

contrary to classes without type parameters compiled successfully:

```
trait Printer {
  def pretty(src : Int) : String
}

final case class Higher[P <: Printer](printer : P) {
  def pass(arg : Int) : String = {
    val pr : Printer = printer
    pr.pretty(arg)
  }
}
```

Is it possible to declare higher-kinded example in a way apprehensible for the compiler?

Comment: Why do you need `P[_]`? Isn't `Printer[X]` sufficient for what you need? Meaning: `final case class Higher[X](printer: Printer[X])`

Comment: I have a more complicated use case. I had posted here the minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use names instead of wildcards, to tell the compiler that the type parameters of `P` and `Printer` are the same.

```
trait Printer[X] {
  def pretty(src : X) : String
}

final case class Higher[P[Y] <: Printer[Y], X](printer : P[X]) {
  def pass(arg : X) : String = {
    val pr : Printer[X] = printer
    pr.pretty(arg)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. I never expected that unbound type parameters like `Y` are allowed in scala